# Vertically Align Div with Absolute Position

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertically align a div (the "p" element in this example but it could be anything a div a link, an image, etc.) which needs to have its position property set to absolute. I followed this example: http://davidwalsh.name/table-cell-position-absolute

But I can get it to work. Here is the code:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 48px; background-color: #EEE; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div style="display: table; position: relative; border: 1px solid blue; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; border: 2px solid green;">
            <div style="position:relative; overflow: auto; height: 100%;">
                <p style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; font-size: 18px; color: black; border: 1px solid orange;">VERTICALLY CENTER ME PLEASE!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqm7wudc/2/

Could someone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually sorted the problem that way:

```
<div style="display: table; position: relative; border: 1px solid red; width: 960; height: 48px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <ul style="display: table; vertical-align: middle; border: 1px solid orange; padding: 0px; position:absolute; left: 700px; margin: 0; height: 100%;"> 
            <li style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 900; padding-right: 20px;"><a href="#">toto</a></li>
            <li style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 20px; font-weight: 900; padding-right: 20px;"><a href="#">titi</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

The text is defined as the content of a list. The ul element is itself a table (positioned using the absolute mode), while the li elements are table cells. This seems to work.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqm7wudc/7/